# c# multipart JSON deserialization

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize multipart JSON message received from httpclient, but I have no experiences with  the multipart message.
The standard complex JSON is no problem thanks to newtonsoft, but I cant deserialize the multipart message.
Is there a package or something for that. I dont want to create some complex code if no needed.

**MESSAGE looks like:**

```
*--------------------------70fc0426e01b4f98
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="event"; 
filename="0001_20220308194235_379109_event_5608_1642.json" 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream*

{"packetCounter":"5608",
"capture_timestamp":"1646764948776",
"frame_timestamp":"0",
"capture_ts":"1646764948776000000",
"datetime":"20220308 194228776",
"plateText":"\u0042\u0041\u0030\u0030\u0036\u0046\u0056",
"plateUnicode":"\u0042\u0041\u0030\u0030\u0036\u0046\u0056",
"plateUTF8":"SL006FV",
"plateASCII":"SL006FV",
"plateCountry":"UK",
"plateConfidence":"0.672017",
"carState":"lost",
"roiID":"1",
"geotag":{"lat": 50.418114,"lon": 30.476213},"imageType": "plate","plateImageType": "png","plateImageSize": "0","carMoveDirection":"in",
"timeProcessing":"0",
"plateCoordinates":[959, 246, 132, 28],
"plateCoordinatesRelative":[0, 0, 0, 0],
"carID":"1642",
"GEOtarget":"Camera",
"imagesURI":["/local/fflprapp/tools.cgi?action=getImage&name=7/20220308194229_354996lp_SL006FV_0.jpg","/local/fflprapp/tools.cgi?action=getImage&name=5/20220308194228_891633roi_SL006FV_0.jpg"],
"imageFile":"/tmp/FFLPR_MMCR/images/5/20220308194228_891633roi_SL006FV_0.jpg",
"camera_info":{"SerialNumber":"000000000000","ProdShortName":"Mobotix M73","MACAddress":"0003C5200D41"},
"sensorProviderID":"23"
}

*--------------------------70fc0426e01b4f98
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="20220308194228_891633roi_SL006FV_0.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg*
```

Comment: Can you show your httpclient code pls?

Comment: `HttpClient` should be parsing the multipart form, so there is probably something wrong with that code

Answer (score -1):

You can use [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) for this.

```
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonText = File.ReadAllText(@"path\to\jsonFile.json");
            JObject jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonText);
            string packetCounter = jsonObject["packetCounter"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

In my example I'm getting the json text from a file. You just need to get it from the httpclient instead. Then you can deserialize it with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` into a `JObject`.